# In a Django Rest Framework 3 Serializer how do I access the request object?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In a Django Rest Framework 3 Serializer how do I access the `request` object?

For example I want to get `META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` i.e...

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    self.request.DATA['key']
    self.request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
    return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

But above gives an error that request is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error for anyone else interested it was

```
self.context['request']
```